# The Random.Range function isn't activating when I call it. How do I get the function to work properly and call from a range of numbers?

Tags: unity, c#, random, debugging

As you can see, I'm attempting to set the random prey integer to a number within a random range like so:

**randomPrey= Random.Range(0,10);**

As I type the code out the .Range doesn't turn yellow and the error code given is CS0117.
I tried doing this in another of my scripts for the same project and It's working fine so it must be something within this script that's causing the function/method to not activate.  Any ideas what it could be?  I would be more than happy to provide more screenshots if needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.VersionControl;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class lionBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{   

private int randomPrey;  

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{        
    randomPrey= Random.Range(0,10);        
}

}
```

Comment: Please copy paste the code in the core of the question, rather than supplying a screenshot... We can't see a thing on mobile...

Comment: You probably imported a different Random.

Comment: Do you have a `using System;` line which would pull in `System.Random`?

Comment: The answer that was provided fixed my issue. I don't know if this is the proper way to respond to comments or not.  Also, is the edited post how I would paste the code into the question? @Vaillancourt   The edit also includes the suggested answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help everyone. :D

Comment: @GideonFalls It would be better to include only the code needed for the question. It is as well not that helpful to edit the question that it now only contains valid code that would make the question itself invalid. The posted code doesnt even contain the Random.Range anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Unity's integrated random methods, you should include the `UnityEngine` namespace in your C# script. This allows you to access Unity's Random class and its `Range` method for generating random numbers within a specified range. Here's how you should do it:

```
using UnityEngine;

// ...

// Now you can use Unity's Random.Range method
float randomValue = Random.Range(minValue, maxValue);
```

Without the `UnityEngine` namespace, attempting to use `Random.Range` directly will result in a compilation error or use of System.Random. So, remember to include the namespace as shown above, and you'll be able to utilize Unity's randomization features seamlessly.

Another common cause of errors is collision with `System.Random`, which can happen if you import the System namespace (with `using System;`). So you can also try to specify which Random class you want use:

```
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
```

You also may check this video-timecode about use of Unity Random class
https://youtu.be/rD8dRtBqTy0?t=3042

Comment: There's no namespace qualification added to `GameObject`,`Vector3`, and `Quaternion` in that code, so it looks like they have the `using UnityEngine;` line already.

Comment: It's worth noting that they can also specify the namespace inline with `int value = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max)`